# CSS Grid columns don't float in Chrome and Firefox, but does in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a simple grid system using CSS, similar to bootstrap. Here's the [page at CodePen](http://codepen.io/Chapman/pen/qqwQzW). 
**The CSS code is:**

```
    /*
* light blue = 00AEEF
* dark blue = 1C75BC
* green = 8DC63F
* dark green = 009444
* orange = F7941E
* dark orange = F15A29
* brown = 594A42
*/


/***************************
****************************
Reset Styles
****************************
***************************/
@import 'normalize.css'

/* Change all elements to use border-box */
html{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/***************************
****************************
Base Styles
****************************
***************************/
body{
    color: #414042 /* Dark Grey */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3{
    font-weight: bold;
}

a{
    color: #8dc63f; /* Green */
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/***************************
****************************
Layout Styles
****************************
***************************/
.container{
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
}

.row{
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

/* ":after" is a pseudo-element (NOT a pseudo-class) */
.row::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* This targets all classes that contain the word "col-" */
[class*='col-']{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Media query excludes extra-small devices and includes small and above */
@media (min-width: 48em) {
    [class*='col-']{
        float: left;

    }

    /* Column One Third */
    .col-1-3{
        width: 33.3333%;
        background: red;
    }

    /* Column Two Thirds */
    .col-2-3{
        width: 66.6666%;
        background: blue;
    }
}




/***************************
****************************
Module Styles
****************************
***************************/


/***************************
****************************
Theme Styles
****************************
***************************/
.background-primary{
    background: #F7941E; /* Orange */
}

.background-secondary{
    background: #00AEEf; /* Blue */
}

.background-tertiary{
    background: #8DC63F; /* Green */
}
```

**The HTML code is:**

```
  <header class="background-primary">
    <div class="container">
        Header Content
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="background-secondary">
        <div class="container">
            Hero Primary Content
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-3">
                    Circle Image
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    Content Area
                </div>
            </div> <!-- End row -->
        </div> <!-- End Container -->
    </section>



    <section>
        <div class="container">
            Featured Content
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-primary">
        <div class="container">
            Testimonial Content
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-secondary">
        <div class="container">
            Media Objects
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-tertiary">
        <div class="container">
            More Content
        </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="background-primary">
    <div class="container">
        Footer Content
    </div>
  </footer>
```

In IE and Edge, both "Circle Image" and "Content Area" floats as expected and appears horizontally. But when viewed in Chrome or Firefox, they are stacked vertically (at least on my side). I suspect this is because of the padding, but why is IE able to handle it properly while other browsers fail? Is this a known error?

(I'm sorry if this is a naive question; but I'm new to web development)

Comment: Just a note, but Bootstrap 4 officially is using Flexbox for layout grids now, instead of floats/clearfixes. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said *"similar to bootstrap"* I will **assume** **you're not using / not willing** to use it (why?)

Now, let's talk grids.

In a grid, **Some dimensions need to be specified** for it to work well.  I would also wrap the whole thing in a `<div>` to contain it.

*If you do that* and you **tell elements** to be nice and not exceed the width of their parent container - using `{max-width:100%}` - you get a nice responsive grid. like so:

(open snippet in *fullscreen* and **resize** your window to see how the elements **stack/un-stack** according to screen width)

```css
/* Start Grid CSS */

.myitem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 260px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
.mycoolcontainer,
.myitem {
  margin: .4em;
}
img,
.mycoolcontainer,
.myitem {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* End CSS */

/* Start visusals */

body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.dark {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#bg1 {
  background: gray
}
#bg2 {
  background: teal
}
#bg3 {
  background: darkgreen
}
#bg4 {
  background: LightSkyBlue
}
#bg5 {
  background: brown
}
#bg6 {
  background: DarkSeaGreen
}
#bg7 {
  background: BurlyWood
}
#bg8 {
  background: Salmon
}
/* End visusals */
```

```html
<div class="mycoolcontainer">


  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg1">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/295/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg2">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/296/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg3">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/297/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg4">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/298/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg5">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/299/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg6">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg7">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/301/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg8">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/302/?random">Title
  </div>


  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg1">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/303/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg2">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/304/?random">Title
  </div>

  <div class="myitem dark" id="bg3">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/305/?random">Title
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this project for personal research purposes (for learning  css) rather than for creating a site. Hence the reason for not using bootstrap.